# C - Copy Array Local To Global - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, arrays

I want to have a global array which can be copied over to a local array for each 'menu selection'. You can specify the size of the array in selection 1 which I feel messes up the global array size when you go to copy the local array to the global array. When trying to accomplish this 'copy' in 'menu 1' you will receive a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error if your 'amount' is to high (10,000+).

Also when exiting the program you receive a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" code 139 error.

So my question is how can I copy a array where I can still have a 'global array' and not run into these errors. I included a few *sizeof array* printf's to check the size because like I said above, I think something needs to be done to change the size of the array before the copy takes place.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    int choice = 0; // menu variable
    int global_amount = 0; //random number generator var's
    int globalArray[0];

    do
    {       
        system("clear");
        printf("Menu\n");
        printf("1: Random Number Generator\n");
        printf("2: Bubble Sort\n");
        printf("3: Exit\n");
        printf("\nNote: Only Random Number Generator Writes To Global Array!\n");
        printf("\nMenu Choice: ");
        scanf ("%d", &choice);

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            system("clear");
            printf("Random Number Generator\n");
            printf("---------\n");          

            printf("Enter the amount of numbers you want (range will be from 0-99): ");
            scanf ("%d", &global_amount);

            int highest = 99;

            // initilize array with size "amount" specified above
            int randArray[global_amount]; 

            int i, randomNumber;

            for(i=0;i<global_amount;i++)
            {
                randomNumber = rand() % highest;
                randArray[i] = randomNumber;
            }

            printf("\nArray Filled With Random Numbers 0 through %d\n\n", highest);

            printf("\nSize of arrays before copy\n");
            printf("randArray - %zu\n", sizeof(randArray));
            printf("globalArray - %zu\n", sizeof(globalArray));

            // copy local array to global array
            for(i=0;i<global_amount;i++)
            {
                globalArray[i] = randArray[i];
            }

            printf("\nSize of arrays after copy\n");
            printf("randArray - %zu\n", sizeof(randArray));
            printf("globalArray - %zu\n", sizeof(globalArray));

            // prints out your array
            printf("\nYour array has these values: \n");
            for(i=0;i<global_amount;i++)
            {
                printf("%d ", globalArray[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");

            printf("\nPress enter to continue...\n");
            char var;scanf ("%c", &var);scanf ("%c", &var);
        }

        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            system("clear");
            printf("Bubble Sort\n");
            printf("---------\n");          

            int i;
            int bubbleArray[global_amount]; // local array

            // copy global array to local array
            for(i=0;i<global_amount;i++)
            {
                bubbleArray[i] = globalArray[i];
            }

            // display array to be sorted
            printf("Your array had these values: \n");
            for(i=0;i<global_amount;i++)
            {
                printf("%d ", bubbleArray[i]);
            }

            // bubble sort code
            int c, d, swap;

            for (c = 0 ; c < ( global_amount - 1 ); c++)
            {
                for (d = 0 ; d < global_amount - c - 1; d++)
                {
                    if (bubbleArray[d] > bubbleArray[d+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
                    {
                        swap       = bubbleArray[d];
                        bubbleArray[d]   = bubbleArray[d+1];
                        bubbleArray[d+1] = swap;
                    }
                }
            }

            printf("\n\nBubble Sort Completed\n");

            // display sorted array
            printf("\n");
            printf("Sorted array list in ascending order:\n");
            for ( c = 0 ; c < global_amount ; c++ )
            {
                printf("%d ", bubbleArray[c]);
            }
            printf("\n");

            printf("\nPress enter to continue...\n");
            char var;scanf ("%c", &var);scanf ("%c", &var);
        }

        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            system("clear");
            return 0;
        }

        else
        {
            system("clear");
            printf("That is not a valid entry.\n");
            printf("Press enter to continue...\n");
            char var;scanf ("%c", &var);scanf ("%c", &var);
        }
    }
    while (choice !=3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: TL;DR! Learn [ask]. And use functions.

Comment: You should grab some tutorial and start of with how arrays work. They're **not** resizeable.

Comment: `int globalArray[0];` : It seems that your array is too small !

Comment: suggest replacing the if/elseif statements for the `choice` variable with a 1switch()1 statement and the `case` code blocks call sub functions to perform the actual work.   This will greatly improve the readability and debug ability of the posted code.

Answer (score 1):

You're "global_array" has a size of zero, so it's basically an address on the stack, and as numbers are copied to it, it overwrites other stack contents.  When you pass the edge of the stack segment, you get `Segmentation fault`.

Your randArray is a C99 VLA (variable length array), which also lives on the stack, but it has an appropriate size.

Note, the term global is usually used for variables having file scope and not living on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C don't resize themselves automatically.  Defining `int globalArray[0];` is not how to do that.

You need to allocate space dynamically for `globalArray` as follows:

```
int *globalArray = NULL;      // initialize to NULL so you can safely clean up

...
        // if globalArray was allocated before, free it
        free(globalArray);
        // allocate space for global_amount ints
        globalArray = malloc(sizeof(int)*global_amount);

        // copy local array to global array
        for(i=0;i<global_amount;i++)
        {
            globalArray[i] = randArray[i];
        }

...

    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        // clean up when you're done
        free(globalArray);
        system("clear");
        return 0;
    }
```

Calling `free` on a NULL pointer is a no-op, which is why we initialize it to NULL.